# LifeRay and Syntax Highlighting / Code Beautifier / Code Formatting

Tags: syntax-highlighting, liferay

I'm experimenting with LifeRay as an internal knowledge base, and a chunk of that content would be code/sql snippets.

What can be done in the area of code coloring / formatting, etc... is there a LifeRay plugin that adds this kind of capability? I did some searching and couldn't find anything.

E.g.:
http://alexgorbatchev.com/SyntaxHighlighter/

Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

Liferay can be configured to use several editors, such as TinyMCE or CKEditor. This configuration is usually done by setting properties in the main portal-ext.properties file, that extends the embedded portal.properties :

```
    # You can configure individual JSP pages to use a specific implementation of
    # the available WYSIWYG editors: ckeditor, ckeditor_bbcode, ckeditor_creole,
    # fckeditor, liferay, simple, tinymce, or tinymce_simple.
    #
    editor.wysiwyg.default=ckeditor
    (...)
    editor.wysiwyg.portal-web.docroot.html.portlet.journal.edit_article_content.jsp=ckeditor
```

It can be used to create a new jsp especially designed to allow the activation of a dedicated syntax editor.
Liferay uses CodePress as a XML editor for some of its configuration, that could be a good start : look at 
liferay-portal-6.1.0/tomcat-6.0.29/webapps/ROOT/html/js/editor/codepress/index.html as a start.

Arnaud